# Why is my function returning null/nil?? - Godot

Tags: null, godot, gdscript

So, I'm trying to make a function that returns a `Dictionary` and for some reason it is returning `Nil` every time I use it. Even though all the endings are returning something! I've restarted the editor and tried some debugging, but couldn't get it to work. Here is my script and error:

Script:

```
func getItem(itemName:String) -> Dictionary:
    if is_name_in_inventory(itemName):
        if inventory.item1.name == itemName:
            return inventory.item1.merge({"index": 1, "error": false})
        elif inventory.item2.name == itemName:
            return inventory.item2.merge({"index": 2, "error": false})
        elif inventory.item3.name == itemName:
            return inventory.item3.merge({"index": 3, "error": false})
        elif inventory.item4.name == itemName:
            return inventory.item4.merge({"index": 4, "error": false})

        print("Unknown error finding an inventory item...")
        return {"error": true, "errormessage": ""}
    
    print("That name does not exist!")
    return {"error": true, "errormessage": "That name does not exist!"}
```

Error:

```
Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'get' in base 'Nil'
```

I am using the function like this: `getItem("item").get("error", false)`

I tried to use a function to get a `Dictionary` and was expecting something **not nil**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `merge` is void. I quote from the official documentation on [merge](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_dictionary.html#class-dictionary-method-merge):

> `void merge ( Dictionary dictionary, bool overwrite=false )`
>
> Adds elements from `dictionary` to this `Dictionary`. By default, duplicate keys will not be copied over, unless `overwrite` is `true`.

Thus, the lines that look like this:

```
return inventory.item1.merge({"index": 1, "error": false})
```

Would:

1. modify the dictionary that you have in `inventory`.
2. return `null`.

And you don't want that.

---

You might be wondering why Godot is not complaining about this. As it turns out, it is a quirk of Godot 3 that `Array` and `Dictionary` are nullable, [*sometimes*](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/162#issuecomment-1272343311).

---

Anyway, you can work around it by declaring the dictionary you want to return. For example:

```
var result := {"index": 1, "error": false}
result.merge(inventory.item1)
return result
```

---

*In other notes, perhaps you would benefit from making `item1`, `item2` and so on into an `Array` so you can iterate over them instead of making an `if` for each one.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going to try this out.